# In CVS, how can I find all the revisions of a file on a certain branch

Tags: version-control, cvs, cvsnt

My source code is versioned with CVS (in particular CVSNT).

Given the full path of a file and the name of a branch, how can I get all the revisions (just the numbers like 1.341.2.1) of the file on the branch?

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for all the revisions of file `bar` in module `foo` on branch 1.341, probably the easiest thing is:

```
grep ^1.341 $CVSROOT/foo/bar,v
```

or you could always do:

```
cvs log bar | grep '^revision 1.341
```